# Stuck at Anglular ui-router State.go with hash url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am working on ui-router. I have a state:

```
.state('new-personal-orders', {
    url: '/orders/new-personal-orders/:catId?',
    template: '<new-personal-orders></new-personal-orders>'
})
```

In my controller i can make the state call with the

```
 $state.go('new-personal-orders',null,{reload:true})
```

In the Html File i have an anchor tag:

```
<a href="/orders/new-personal-orders#12">Link</a>
```

If the tag is clicked the state changes and 'new-personal-orders' turns into the current state with the trailing hash in the url. The url then looks like:

**http://localhost:3000/orders/new-personal-orders#12**

I want to do the same from the controller file with the $state.go() function of ui-router. But the hash url is not added.

My question is that is there any way that the hash url can be passed by the $state.go() in ui-router?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you can now put a hash in the state params like so:

```
$state.go('new-personal-orders', {'#': catId });
```

And you don't even need a `/:catId` in the state configuration at all.
See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1867

Answer (score 0):

You can pass state params as an argument in `$state.go` :

```
$state.go('new-personal-orders', {catId: 12}, {reload:true})  
// refers to: http://localhost:3000/orders/new-personal-orders/#12
```

It seems that you are attempting to implement the same inside an `ng-repeat`, then you should replace `12` by something such as `order.catId` etc.

Comment: Actually 12 is not a parameter that i want to pass . http://localhost:3000/orders/new-personal-orders#12. A Hash Url instead .

Comment: A hash url would automatically be constructed by using `$state.go`, if you define the stateParams correctly. It seems futile to manually re-construct the already referred url of a state.